# What can be an optimized algorithm for modifying a pie chart with a minimum amount of repainting?

Tags: algorithm

For example I have a pie chart drawn where I have n number of components and I have their percentage values in an array. And now I get the array of percentage updated and I want to repaint the pie chart. Is there any algorithm to draw it with minimum change of coloring required?
I was thinking that A* can be the optimum solution but finding the heuristic for this problem is hard.

Comment: I’d say, in the end implementing such an algorithm might be more costly than just doing a complete repaint …

Comment: @CBroe Agreed with you but still for the sake of solution what can be the algorithm? It seems quite interesting problem since it has got so many variables.

Comment: Gives a new meaning to the graph coloring problem :)

Comment: @Naman: Usually when pie charts represent percentages, any single update changes all the slices. Are your updates are somehow different?

Comment: @LiorKogan: I agree with you, but i want to repaint them in such a manner that I'll need minimum amount of repainting. For example section A increased from 20% to 25% then the 20% area which was showing A suppose in red color should not be repainted.

Comment: I've removed the `graph-algorithm` tag from this question which is not within that domain.

Comment: @Naman: What about the order of the slices? Is it important to keep the same order?

Comment: @LiorKogan I guess both can be two different problems as with ordering an without ordering. But for now we can take as ordering is not important.

Comment: Use the greatest common divider of the percentages to figure out what sized slices to divide the graphs into. Now it's a matter of mapping slices of unit size from the new pie graph to the old pie graph. I would recommend using Integer Programming with constraints to ensure each unit has one color. An objective function would minimize the changes in color required.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I wouldn't bother I'd just repaint the pie chart.  I expect the time saved by not repainting unchanged parts of the chart will be overwhelmed by the time spent figuring out what to change.

Nevertheless, here's an idea:

Draw your pie charts as a set of 100 triangles arranged in a circle.  If 100 isn't enough to make the chart look pretty, choose some integer multiple of 100.  Suppose that segment A is 20% of the original chart and is the first (counting clockwise from 12 o'clock) segment in the chart.  On painting simply colour triangles 1-20 as you wish.  If segment A expands to 25%, repaint triangles 21-25.  And so on.

I don't think I've ever seen a pie chart where fractions of percentages were visually meaningful so I wouldn't sweat over dealing with values such as 23.8%, I'd just round them.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution. I simply tried to formalize the problem and see if I can come up with something. I'm afraid the the problem has no solution with low computational cost.

Let's start by formalizing the problem:

**Input:**

Two ordered sets of n points on the circumference of a circle:

A(1)..A(n) and B(1)..B(n), each defines a set of arcs such that

- Before the change: arc m is between angle A(m) and angle A(mod(m+1,n))
- After the change: arc m is between angle B(m) and angle B(mod(m+1,n))

**Basic Math:**

The arc-length of the arc between angle x and y is *mod(y-x,360)* (arcs are notated clockwise).

where *mod(a,b) = a-b**floor(a/b)*

We'll mark *O(a1,a2,b1,b2)* as the intersection between arc [a1,a2) and arc [b1,b2).

Note the two arcs can have between 0 and 2 intersections. e.g O(270,100,90,280)= {[270,280),[90,100)}, while O(10,20,30,40)= {}

We'll mark *L(a1,a2,b1,b2)* as the arc-length of the larger intersection between arc [a1,a2) and arc [b1,b2) .

I won't describe the calculation of L(a1,a2,b1,b2) here.

**Special case: Keeping the same order of arcs:**

Find a drawing offset *w* that maximizes

*L(A(1),A(2),mod(B(1)+w,360),mod(B(2)+w,360)) +*

*L(A(2),A(3),mod(B(2)+w,360),mod(B(3)+w,360)) + ... +*

*L(A(n),A(1),mod(B(n)+w,360),B(1),mod(B(1)+w,360)*

**General case: Without keeping the same order of arcs:**

Find both

- An permutation of the order of the set of arcs that are defined by points set B
- A drawing offset w

That maximizes the same expression as in the special case.

**My thoughts**

I'm afraid that due to the noncontinuity of the modulo function, there is no easy way to find an optimal solution.

For the special case, you may simply search for an optimal *w* starting with a given resolution (e.g. 0.1 degrees), and increase the resolution near the best w's (You don't need a sub-pixel resolution anyway).

As for the general case, I believe that you'll have to find a good heuristic for limiting the permutations set - maybe by leaving large arcs at about the same places.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing its not just repainting work your after but.. make dubbelbuffer, compare, paint difference.